# Nagios showing "OK" state despite being in CRITICAL

Tags: nagios

I'm using nagios to monitor various services in our production environment. But for one such service, I noticed that nagios is showing "OK" state despite the service being down and not running. I'm using check_http plugin to achieve the same. On running the check command on cli of the server, I get the result as below. I notice that the exit status code returned is 2, which indicates a CRITICAL state for nagios. But, instead the state being shown is "OK". Any pointers on how to deal with this problem is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

> > me@myserver:~$ check_http -H localhost -p 8180 -u /SomeService/services?_wadl
> >
> > Connection refused
> >
> > HTTP CRITICAL - Unable to open TCP socket
> >
> > me@myserver:~$ echo $?
> >
> > 2

Comment: Please post the relevant 'check_command' line from the nagios configuration file of the host. The command is under the service definition.

Answer (score 2):

Your manual test doesn't match what Nagios is doing.

Most likely, you're passing ARGs to check_http that are being ignored. Compare the command definition for the service check_command you're using with your manual test.

If you haven't already, be sure to read the docs page on [Macros and How They Work](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/macros.html).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the pointers keith and Daniel. I figured out the solution to the problem.

The check command URL path parameter configured in the NConf was

> /SomeService/services?_wadl&_type=xml

But on checking /var/log/syslog on the server, I could find the URL path actually being executed was /SomeService/services?_wadl ( Pls note the stripping of "type=xml" part).

On running the check command with these two URL paths separately, I noticed that, I had to hit an "Enter" key to get the exit status of the command with URL containing "type=xml", which explains why nagios never got the exit status 2. While the other URL returned the exit status without any manual intervention.

> me@myserver:$ check_http -H localhost -p 8180 -u /SomeService/services?_wadl&_type=xml
>
> [1] 3543
>
> me@myserver:$ Connection refused
>
> HTTP CRITICAL - Unable to open TCP socket
>
> [Hit Enter and then I get my exit status]
>
> [1]+  Exit 2                  check_http -H localhost -p 8180 -u /SomeService/services?_wadl
>
> me@myserver:$ check_http -H localhost -p 8180 -u /SomeService/services?_wadl
>
> Connection refused
>
> HTTP CRITICAL - Unable to open TCP socket
>
> [I instantly got my exit status without manual intervention]

On changing the URL path in the Nconf to /SomeService/services?_wadl, I started getting correct exit status and nagios started reporting CRITICAL when the service actually went down. But I'm still wondering, why does check_http plugin wait for a user intervention to return the exit code when the URL contains a "&_type=xml"?

Comment: In your manual testing, the & is causing the job to background. You have to escape this so the shell doesn't process it.